# How to increase the font size of one word only in the line?

Tags: html, css

I have to increase the size of a word in a middle of a normal font-size sentence.

```
<p class="call">To book a consultation click here or call NOW</p>
```

How can I enlarge the NOW word in CSS? If I create new paragraph the word will go to the new line.
Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<p class="call">To book a consultation click here or call <span class='bigger'>NOW</span></p>
```

with CSS

```
.bigger { font-size:200%; }
```

Comment: Just to elaborate: the point here is the distinction between inline elements and block elements. You may want to take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Yes, absolutely - I have slapped myself roundly. I would never use somthing like 'bigger' like this - purely for illustrative puroposes

Answer (score 7):

1. Decide **why** you want it to be bigger (the point is HTML is to describe semantics, not presentation, so you need to think about this sort of thing)
2. Write appropriate semantic markup
3. Apply CSS

Perhaps:

```
<p class="call">To book a consultation click here or call <em>now</em></p>
```

and in your stylesheet:

```
em {  /* or .call em, but you should aim for consistency in your styling */
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This will also work

```
<p> This is some <b> TEXT </b><p>
```